# Не работает код на jsfiddle

Tags: jsfiddle, javascript

Добрый день! У меня странный глюк случился. На сервисе [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pc4me/2/) простейший код не работает (в разных браузерах), а если в отдельный html-формировать то работает. С чем это связанно? У других сервис jsfiddle работает?

```js
function count_rabbits() 
{
    for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
    // оператор + соединяет строки
    alert("Из шляпы достали "+i+" кролика!")
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="count_rabbits()" value="Считать кроликов!"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В левом углу выберите не `"onLoad"`, а `"no wrap - in <head>"`.